# Displaying by default shipping fields on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, billing

On my WooCommerce checkout page, I am selling only one product. The checkout page is showing this product and there is **ckeckbox** next to it, to show the shipping details, when clicked. This is on the default **`form-checkout.php`** WooCommerce template.

I would like to have this **ckeckbox** always selected, to  show billing details by default.

I have tried to set:

```
$checkout = 1;
```

With no luck so far. The radio button is displayed by the following hook:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details'); ?>
```

Any help letting me know how I can achieve this will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look to the code of **`checkout/form-shipping.php`** WooCommerce template, inside the **`<h3>`** tag, where the checkbox code is located, there is **`woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked`** hook that you can use to achieve that. Here is an extract of this code template, that shows it:

```
?>
<div class="woocommerce-shipping-fields">
    <?php if ( true === WC()->cart->needs_shipping_address() ) : ?>

        <h3 id="ship-to-different-address">
            <label for="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="checkbox"><?php _e( 'Ship to a different address?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="input-checkbox" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1" />
        </h3>

        <div class="shipping_address">
```

So you can use this hook this way, to get this checkbox always selected and displays billing details:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_true');
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

Comment: Hi, actualy the radio button which I want to have checked is the one which is closed inside: <div id="opc-messages"><ul id="checkout-products"> tags, bot the shpping address. do you have any idea where this code comes from ?

Comment: the radio button code which I need checked is the following: `<input type="radio" id="product_1987" name="add_to_cart" value="1987" data-add_to_cart="1987" />`